# how to serve cloudfront pages through a external server(localhost)?

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, nginx-ingress

i have my cloudfront at `mycdn.cloudfront.net` . it serves two pages at `/` and `/about`. Also an S3 bucket from which cloudfront gets the files.
i have a server at `localhost:3000` which needs to serve the pages from the cloudfront at same paths. when i tried routing the requests to the cloudfront using nginx i got 403 bad request error. I found that when we have a domain name to send the pages through, using cloudfront, we use CNAME. i also set actual pages to served as error pages at 403 and 404 http error codes. i have set redirection to https from https(also previously added support for http and https).
how to get my react pages as and at

`mycdn.cloudfront.net/` **-at->**  `localhost:3000/`

`mycdn.cloudfront.net/about` **-at->**  `localhost:3000/about`